# Is it possible to have Angular react on click event without DOM manipulation?

Tags: angular, svg

I have managed to have my [Angular(8)](https://angular.io/) application react to a click on a loaded svg image.
I don't like my solution as the Angular component code knows about the innards of the svg file and also does some DOM manipulation.

Is there a way to get rid of the [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) and [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)?

Component code:

```
@Component({ ... })
export class StartPageComponent {

  @ViewChild('startimage', {static:false})
  private startimage: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const svg = this.startImage.nativeElement.getSVGDocument();

    //  We have to wait until the image is loaded to have its elements populated.
    this.startImage.nativeElement.addEventListener('load', () => {

      const button1 = svg.getElementById('g-element1');
      button1.addEventListener('click', () => {

        // With this solution the whole page blinks.
        // It would be nicer to have it just do a regular Angular route.
        window.location.href = '/somepage;
      });

      const button2 = svg.getElementById('g-element2');
      button2.addEventListener('click', () => {
        ..
      });
    });
  }
}
```

The html file:

```
<embed #startimage id="startimage" src="/assets/startimage.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>
```

The svg file:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  ...
  <g id="g-element1">
    ...
  </g>
  <g id="g-element2">
    ...
  </g>
  ...
</svg>
```

Comment: did try to wrap this embed tag into a div element and put (click) event on the div and just work with a method binded to the click event ? (click)="method()" then in the method() {
this.router.navigate...
} ??

Comment: I updated the code to show that I want clicks *inside* the svg, not that the svg was clicked.